# Which statement is true: *  log  = () *  = (^2) * ^2 = ( log ) * ln  = (1)

Tags: algorithm

Which statement is true:

- log  = ()
- = (^2)
- ^2 = ( log )
- ln  = (1)

I'm studying for the exam and found this example. No idea, what answer is true. I shoot the 4th one

Comment: This question might be better for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 2nd one though you better ask such questions to other communities e.g cs

Comment: If you're having trouble figuring this out, you should probably read the part of your textbook that explains what big-O means, or look for a better explanation online.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is right.
If you are unable to remember the logic/ theory. just always remember

> smaller functions = O(Bigger functions)

So clearly,

*log   **>**  so FALSE

^2 **>**  log  so FALSE

ln  = logn **>** 1 so FALSE

and,

< (^2) so TRUE.

i.e. Smaller function ( n ) is in Big Oh of Bigger function(n^2)